# xmlhttp request has strange behavior and has status = 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a Google Chrome extension that upon pressing a button executes an xmlhttp request to a server. I'm currently handling the error if the server is down. What I want to achieve is to retry the request after an increasing number of seconds. That's how I do it:

```
var execute = function(method, url, i){
            //if timeout doesn't exist, create one
            if(!i){
                i = 1000;
            }

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlhttp.status != 200)  {
                    // Handle error, retry request
                    console.log("xmlhttp.status = " + xmlhttp.status + " and xmlhttp.readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState);
                    setTimeout("execute('"+method+"', '"+url+"', "+i*2+")", i);
                    return;
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
```

Basically if there is some kind of problem I retry again the request. If the server is up, there is no problem at all, but if the server is down JavaScript throws me an error saying:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/buy/2/id=1329664820124 
executepopup.html:127
(anonymous function)
```

Which is not really meaningful, but however. The status in the log says "0", which is pretty lame too. If I turn on the server again while this is going on, it should stop doing this, but instead also if it succeeds (I see a log in the server that tells me that it received the request), it keeps calling the `execute` method. I don't know how to stop this recursion if the server turns on. Am I doing something wrong? Is this state equal zero the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where do you run this code? In a contentscript, or in the background page? What's the full code? Have you already added the domain to the `permissions` section of `manifest.json`?

Comment: Yes the domain is added, otherwise it could not communicate to the server, right? This code runs in the pop-up page of my extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solving the problem

`onreadystatechange` is triggered for every state change, from state 0 to 4, and many times between. You should only be interested in `readyState` 4, because the request has fully finished at that point.

To get your method to work, check whether `xmlhttp.readyState == 4`:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200)  {
```

---

## Fixing your horrible implementation of setTimeout

`setTimeout("execute('"+method+"', '"+url+"', "+i*2+")", i);` is **not** the right way to call a function again. Since you're developing in a Chrome extension, you can use the following format for `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(execute, i, method, url, i*2);
// Calls execute(method, url, i*2) after i milliseconds.
```

Comment: That seems to solve the problem. So what I was missing was the knowledge that `onreadystatechange` is triggered for every single state change. Thanks also for the cute explanation about `setTimeout`.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it's still not working. It seems like even though the server receives something when it goes up, the piece of code keeps sending stuff, like if there is always an error and keeps scheduling the `setTimeout` method. This is because the `status` is always `!= 200` (always zero as the title says).

Comment: @Masiar That's not a bug in the JavaScript code, but at the server's side (or the understanding of it). You can easily debug this by putting `console.log(xmlhttp.status);` within the `if` block. Then, watch the console, and check the logged status code (etc).

Comment: I'll take a look at the server side implementation. I know how to use `console.log()` :) thanks anyway. At least *this* part of code is correct.